# C# SortedList with Byte Array as Key

Tags: c#, arrays, icomparer

I want to compare byte arrays used as keys in a SortedList

```
public SortedList<byte[], string> myList = new SortedList<byte[], string>();
```

the problem is, that I cant add entries into myList, because .NET doesnt know how to compare two elements of the list ("Error comparing two elements in array"):

```
byte[] bytearray = {0,0,25,125,250}; // Example 
string description = "Example Value";
myList.Add(bytearray, description);
```

After a bit of googling I read something about implementing **my own IComparer Class**. I've searched further but didn't found anything about an IComparer implementation for byte arrays. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

**Quick Edit:**
Thanks for the answers! I've implemented the IComparer from the answer provided:

```
    class ByteComparer : IComparer<byte[]>
    {
        public int Compare(byte[] x, byte[] y)
        {
            var len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                var c = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
                if (c != 0)
                {
                    return c;
                }
            }

            return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
        }
    }
```

And calling it with:

```
    public SortedList<byte[], string> myList = new SortedList<byte[], string>(new ByteComparer());
```

Comment: Just do a Array.SequenceEquals between the values in **your own IComperer** implementation.

Comment: But doesnt it return only one value that is useful for me? SequenceEquals would provide me the information if the arrays are equal, how about being "larger" or "lower" (1,0,-1 values for IComprarer) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
class ByteComparer : IComparer<byte[]>
{
    public int Compare(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        var len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            var c = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
            if (c != 0)
            {
                return c;
            }
        }

        return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
    }
}
```

This can even be extended to a generic class for comparing arrays of any type which implements `IComparable<T>`:

```
class ArrayComparer<T> : IComparer<T[]>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public int Compare(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        var len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            var c = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
            if (c != 0)
            {
                return c;
            }
        }

        return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
    }
}
```

This will find the first element which differs between the two arrays, and return a value indicating which comes first according the types default ordering. If there are no differences, it will return a value indicating which array is shorter.

Comment: Nice, really elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that implement the `IComparer<byte[]>` interface.  This interface has one method - `public int Compare(byte[] first, byte[] second)`.  The method should return a negative int if `first < second`, 0 if `first == second`, and a positive int if `first > second`.  You'll need to work out what `<`, `==`, and `>` mean in your application and write the method accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Great addition to p.s.w.g 's answer!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your logic flow. What does it mean `byte array a` is less than `byte array b`? What should you compare? Anyway, you just have to implement one simple method: `int Compare(byte[] x, byte[] y)`